# NoMethodError: undefined method `task' for Sinatra::Application:Class

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This is the error I get when I run any rake command: undefined method 'task' for Sinatra::Application:Class

```
# Rakefile
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require_relative './config/environment'
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}



#lib/tasks/test_report.rake
namespace :test_report do
  task :generate => :environment do
    ...
  end
end
```

I run into the above error when I tried to run the command.

```
bundle exec rake test_report:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use rake API, but it's not loaded. Add this on top of your file.

```
require 'rake'
```